# Error exporting a document in google docs api

Tags: java, oauth, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to retrieve a document like this:

```
  client.setAuthSubToken(token);
  String contentUri = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?docID="+ entry.getDocId()
                            + "&exportFormat=txt&format=txt";

  MediaContent mc = new MediaContent();
  mc.setUri(contentUri);

  MediaSource ms = client.getMedia(mc);
  InputStream inStream = ms.getInputStream();
```

But am getting the next error:

`com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector handleResponse
ADVERTENCIA: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {authsub=WWW-Authenticate: AuthSub realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest"}`

Do not why if my client is authenticated, hope some one can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the line where you actually send the request?

Comment: in this line  MediaSource ms = client.getMedia(mc); is sending the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

1. Replace **docId** parameter with **id** parameter

   ```
   contentUri = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + entry.getDocId() + "&exportFormat=txt&format=txt";
   ```
2. Use directly the method for obtaining the uri  (This is recommended)

   ```
   String contentUri = ((MediaContent) entry.getContent()).getUri();
   contentUri = contentUri + "&exportFormat=txt&format=txt";
   ```